Azure Database Auditing not capturing login failures
I'm looking to capture login failures against our Azure Database. I've set up auditing on my Azure Database as such

After running some queries, I can see login successes for the principal in question, shown by the action_id DBAS eg

However, when generating failures both from SSMS and our application, the auditing doesnt capture any failures, which I expect to be shown with action_id DBAF
The info box for this auditing option does say its supposed to capture login failures. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?


How can a login failure have server principle name set?

If you provide a correct username but incorrect password? In any case, just searching for action_id = 'DBAF' returns no results

Perhaps you select from wrong xel file because it has rolled over, who can tell. Also, aren't you looking for FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP rather than what you wrote? DB auth failure sounds like something like database access failed

The source file part of the script was auto generated by Azure, so hopefully that should be correct. Im not sure which group to look for to be honest, as long as it has login failures. Ill have a look at FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP, thanks

Make sure you have given correct file path. Try with below query:
select event_time,server_instance_name,database_name,action_id,server_principal_name,application_name from sys.fn_get_audit_file
('https://banuadls.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/dbservere/db/SqlDbAuditing_Audit_NoRetention/2024-05-31/08_44_54_724_0.xel',default,default)  
where event_time <=  '2024-05-31T09:11:00.5349194'

It is giving login failed error audits as shown below:



event_time
server_instance_name
database_name
action_id
server_principal_name
application_name




2024-05-31T08:44:55.3341817
dbservere

AUSC
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Internal


2024-05-31T08:45:13.8966156
dbservere
db
DBAF
server
Azure SQL Query Editor


2024-05-31T08:45:14.7871436
dbservere
db
DBAF
server
Azure SQL Query Editor


2024-05-31T08:45:21.8808280
dbservere
db
DBAF
server
Azure SQL Query Editor


2024-05-31T08:54:55.4361409
dbservere
db
DBAF
server
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio


2024-05-31T08:55:18.9358867
dbservere
db
DBAF
server
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio


2024-05-31T09:11:00.5349194
dbservere
db
DBAS
server
Azure SQL Query Editor


2024-05-31T09:11:00.5349194
dbservere
db
BCM
server
Azure SQL Query Editor



For more information you refer to this SO answer.
